# owl-carousel dots not appearing in the middle of the slides

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a website and trying to use owl-carousel to display each of my skills. I'm trying to display the dots at the end of the slides. However, only the navigation arrows seem to appear. I can drag the items but the dots do not appear.

Any help would be appreciated.

Javascript:

```
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  nav: true,
  items: 1,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplayTimeout: 2000,
  autoplayHoverPause: true,
  dots: true,
  responsive:{
    0:{
      items:1
    },
    480:{
      items:2
    },
    768:{
      items:3
    },
    938:{
      items:4
    }  
  }
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzH56.png)

The nav arrows show up however the dots do not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you including Owl Carousel's theme files. It looks like the default css only has basic styling. The theme css is the one that includes styling for elements such as the dots:

```js
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  nav: true,
  items: 1,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplayTimeout: 2000,
  autoplayHoverPause: true,
  dots: true,
  responsive:{
    0:{
      items:1,
    },
    480:{
      items:2,
    },
    768:{
      items:3,
    },
    938:{
      items:4,
    }  
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>6</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>7</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>8</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>9</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>10</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>11</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>12</h4></div>
</div>
```

Comment: yup, it was the fact I didn't have the theme file. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which version of Owl Carousel you are using, which might determine the parameter for controlling the dots in your init function. But you can search the HTML on the page for `class="owl-dots"` which is the class normally given to this container. Check if the css is set to `display: none;`. If it is, then you might not be specifying the right code to show the dots which would remove this class. So you can either find the documentation to set it in your init function, or just set a CSS rule of `.owl-dots {display: block !important;}`. You may also need this to make the buttons line up horizontally: `.owl-dots .owl-dot { display: inline-block;}`

Answer (score 0):

put `center: true` in this `$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({})` initialiser. Hope it will work

Comment: Thanks for the help.I added this to the function however kinda uncentered each element.